# Embedding an excel file into a power point and linking data

Tags: excel, hyperlink, powerpoint

I'm trying to embed an excel file into a power point, and link data from the embedded excel to the power point. The problem is that when I'm doing that, the linked data is not being automatically updated in power point, whereas if i link data from an external excel file the data gets automatically synced.

Summary:
power point + external excel link = automatic sync
power point + embedded excel link = static link, doesn't update data when data in excel is changed.

Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: XL and other such content can be embedded OR linked. Not both. Embedded XL files are contained entirely within the PPT and have no link to the original XL file. The only way to update them is to activate them (either in code our by doubleclicking them etc.) and editing then closing them.  Linked files will be updated from the source when you open the PPT/PPTX (unless the links are set not to update automatically). Or you can update them in code via the OLE object's .Update method.